# HTML Image tag is not working in Windows Box

Tags: html

i am working on html page, so i am including image in that page using img tag.

```
<img src="file:///C:/wamp/www/images/Sat.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>
```

But its not working !!!

Comment: Are you running your page on a web server, or just opening it in your browser? Try using `src="/images/Sat.png"` or `src="images/Sat.png"`

Comment: I assume you are working with WAMP and have this server on? Why won't you try something like `http://localhost/images/Sat.png` instead?

Comment: Still not working  <img src="/images/3.png" class="img-circle" alt="User Image"/>

Comment: If i use http://localhost/images/Sat.png its take more time to reflect

Comment: i am not using wamp server here, i am running application in tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

In your case details about your environment (like your browser, server and operating system) can become really necessary to help and solve your problem.

To your current issue I predict that you used the Firefox or Chrome browser. In this case you should know that both browsers preventing and blocking access to your local files.

- **To access you should disabling the security check of your browser!**

Here are the steps (found on [Jonathan Li's Blog](http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.de/2016/01/disable-same-origin-and-local-url.html)):

**Safari**

> 1. Enable develop-menu (Preferences -> Advanced -> "Show develop menu in menu bar")
> 2. Click "Develop" in the menubar
> 3. Select "Disable local file restrictions"

**Firefox**

> 1. Enter "about:config" in your adress-bar and accept.
> 2. Find "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" parameter
> 3. Set the value to *false*

**Chorme**

> Start your Chrome (or create a shourtcut for it) with the following arguments, like:
>
> `C:\PATH-TO-YOUR-CHROME-INSTALL\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: Thanks Sascha, i am checking this config changes in my browser and let you know in few minuts.

Comment: No Luck, Still i am not able to view the image

Comment: More details, operating system, installed security tools (firewalls, antivirus, security suites) and did you tried it also with the different browsers? How it behaves on other machines?